# How do I handle extra headers appended to top of file via PUT?

Tags: php, postman

I am developing an API using PHP.

I am accepting an XML file via PUT request.

Developing my app with Postman I see the following:

```
------WebKitFormBoundary0ASxhcJEf0dqxS1P
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""; filename="books.xml"
Content-Type: text/xml


<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
    <book id="bk101">
        <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
        <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
        <genre>Computer</genre>
        <price>44.95</price>
        <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
        <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
    </book>
...
</catalog>

------WebKitFormBoundary0ASxhcJEf0dqxS1P--
```

I've brought it in via `echo file_get_contents("php://input")`.

Can I intercept or sanitize this extra data that appears to be from WebKit?

Comment: how is that request made?

Comment: @DanielA.White with Postman I attach the file via form-data

Comment: don't do it with form data.

Comment: Are you asking about the boundary?

Comment: @DanielA.White please elaborate. What are better alternatives? Why? It'd make a great answer.

Comment: @AlanPerez yes, and the headers passed in before the actual payload (the opening xml tag).

Comment: If you are building an API and only need to send xml via this endpoint. I would send the request with a content type of application/xml rather than multipart/form-data encoding. Then simply send the body of the request as xml. No need to worry about additional complexities of multipart form encoding plus it seems more appropriate for an api.

Comment: thanks @AlanPerez. i will be converting the contents to database objects. working on my php chops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form data is really only for HTML forms, not APIs. What you have done is like a `<input type="file">`.

Either select `raw` or `binary`.